# How to invoke multiple python scripts from the same Process in C#

Tags: c#, python, process, parallel-processing, interop

I am currently working on a project that involves executing python scripts from c# (ironPython is not an option). I am trying to increase the speed of execution whilst running many scripts. So far, I have managed to increase performance by running each process in a task in order to parallelise the work.

Is it possible to add several scripts to an already instantiated process, and then run them in order to reduce the overhead of creating many new processes and reuse existing ones? I figured that creating all of these new processes is a massive bottleneck.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at pythonnet?

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet